gesturedetector - Fluuter : how shift recognition a to b in stack?
(Please understand that my English skills are not proficient)
Let's say there are two GestureDetector widgets, 'a' and 'b', where 'a' is positioned above 'b' in a stack. Initially, dragging occurs within 'a', but when the drag exceeds a certain threshold, I want 'b' to move to the top of the stack and 'a' to move below 'b', with 'b' then recognizing the ongoing drag. Essentially, I want the widget recognizing the drag to switch seamlessly within a single continuous drag (both 'a' and 'b' occupying the same space).
However, currently, even when 'a' moves below 'b', it still continues to recognize the drag. I want it to switch to 'b' without requiring the user to lift their finger and drag again.
Could you please assist me with this?
here's my code
class Curr_to_prev extends StatefulWidget {

  State<Curr_to_prev> createState() => _Curr_to_prevState();
}

class _Curr_to_prevState extends State<Curr_to_prev>{
  late Stack currentStack;
  late Widget page1;
  late Widget page2;

  void initState() {
    page1 = Test(color: Colors.red,change: change);
    page2 = Test(color: Colors.blue,change: change);
    currentStack = Stack(
      children: [page2,page1],
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    // return currentStack;
    return currentStack;
  }

  void change(){
    setState(() {
      currentStack = Stack(
        children: [page1,page2],
      );
    });
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  Test({
    required this.change,
    required this.color
  }) : super(key: UniqueKey());
  final VoidCallback change;
  final Color color;
  @override
  State<Test> createState() => TestState();
}

class TestState extends State<Test>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  double temp = 0;


  void _onHorizontalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    double newPointer = temp + details.primaryDelta!;
    if(newPointer<-150 ){
      widget.change();
      return;
    }
    temp = newPointer;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
      child: Container(
        color : widget.col,
        height: 300,
        width : 300,
      )
    );
  }
}

